# Partial View in MVC 5

Tags: partial-views

This is my code, I don't know why I have this error when I build it.

> Error 1   'ShopingCart.Models.ApplicationDbContext' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Items' and no extension method 'Items' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'ShopingCart.Models.ApplicationDbContext' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
Controller Code:
public class ItemsController : Controller
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public PartialViewResult _GetForCart(int CartID)
    {
        List<Item> items = context.Items.Where(i => i.CartID == CartID).ToList();
        ViewBag.CartID = CartID;
        return PartialView("_GetForCart", items);     

    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult _ItemsForm(int CartID)
    {
        Item item = new Item() { CartID = CartID };
        return PartialView("_ItemsForm", item);
    }

    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
    public PartialViewResult _Submit(Item item)
    {
        context.Items.Add(item);
        context.SaveChanges();

        List<Item> items = context.Items.Where(i => i.CartID == item.CartID).ToList();
        ViewBag.CartID = item.CartID;
        return PartialView("_GetForCart", items);
```

Model Code:

```
public class Item
    {
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }

        public int CartID { get; set; }

        public virtual Cart Cart { get; set; }
    }

public class Cart
    {
        public int CartID { get; set; }
        public string CartName { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What does the definition of your dbcontext class look lik

Comment: oh i have another controller which I scaffolding it. public class CartsController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: Carts
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Carts.ToList());
        }

Comment: I don't have DBcontext class

Comment: I have applicationDBcontext class which is default of MVC public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ShopingCart.Models.Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Oh i found this, just add one more line to my ApplicationDbcontext class "    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ShopingCart.Models.Item> Items { get; set; }"